# javascript fetch and promise not returning data

Tags: javascript

I use `fetch` to load `json` data which works fines. I am trying to return that data back to another function but I am getting `undefined`. It should be a simple `return` because the data is there. Am I doing something wrong inside the `then`?

The `console.log(data);` displays that data fine. However `console.log(gameData);` gives me an `undefined`

```
(function loadGameData () {
   var gameData = loadData('assets/gameData.json');
   console.log(gameData);
})();

function loadData(json) {
    fetch(json)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            return(data);
        }); 
}
```

Comment: You are trying to get an asynchronous result in a synchronous way. That is like pressing the Order button on a pizza website and be surprised that your plate is still empty. Moreover `loadData` doesn't return anything. You must wait for the data to be available, so (1) *return* the `fetch.....then()` result, (2) make `loadData` an `async` function, and (3) get the result with `= await loadData(...)`. All info in related dupe reference.

Comment: ah ok makes sense, thanks